# What's the probability that hitting shuffle on an album of 5 tracks 10 times will allow you to see the original order at least once?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I wanted to validate my approach, since I'm off from a solutions script I have on hand.

The probability of getting the original tracklist is $p_s = \frac{1}{5!} = \frac{1}{120}$

Then using the Binomial RV:

${{10}\choose{1}}p_s(1-p_s)^9 = 0.077$

Is this a correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation is the probability of seeing the order *exactly* once (the term $p_s (1-p_s)^9$ means you see it once and then the other 9 times you don't see it).  To calculate the probability of seeing it at least once, it's easier to calculate the probability of never seeing it, then subtract from 1: $$1 - (1-p_s)^{10}.$$